# EF MVC4 C#: Many to Many Relationship with "relationship property" DB First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I've already spent the last few days trying to fix my problem, sadly without any result. I've already  read countless post on here on this subject, but I keep getting the same error. "Unknown column 'Extent1.foo_id' in 'field list'"... What am I doing wrong? My mapping has to be wrong some way, but I fail to see how...

Edit: It's database first!

I also have another class "Doo" which has a many to many relationship with "Foo" but that one is working fine.

Thanks in advance!

```
  public class Foo
        {

        public Foo()
            {
            this.FooBoo = new Collection<FooBoo>();
            }        

        public String FooId { get; set; }        
        public virtual ICollection<FooBoo> FooBoo { get; set; }

        }


         public class Boo
            {

            public Boo()
                {
                this.FooBoo = new Collection<FooBoo>();    
                }

                    public String BooId { get; set; }    
                    public virtual ICollection<FooBoo> FooBoo { get; set; }  
                }

         public class FooBoo
            {        
                public String Fooid { get; set; }

                public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }

                public String Booid { get; set; }        

                public virtual Boo Boo { get; set; } 

                public Boolean RandomProperty { get; set; }       

            }

         public class BooMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<Boo>
            {

                public BooMapper()
                {

                    this.HasKey(t => t.BooId);


                    this.Property(t => t.BooId).HasColumnName("booid");

            this.ToTable("boo", "fooboodb");

                    this.HasMany(t => t.FooBoo)
                        .WithRequired()
                        .HasForeignKey(t => t.Booid);
                }
            }


         public class FooMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
            {

                public FooMapper()
                {

                    this.HasKey(t => t.FooId);


                    this.Property(t => t.FooId).HasColumnName("fooid");
                        .
            this.ToTable("foo", "fooboodb");

                    this.HasMany(t => t.FooBoo)
                        .WithRequired()
                        .HasForeignKey(t => t.Booid);
                }
            }

         public class FooBooMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<FooBoo>
            {
            public FooBooMapper()
                {

                this.HasKey(t => new {t.Fooid, t.Booid});

                this.Property(t => t.Fooid);

                this.Property(t => t.Booid);

                this.Property(t => t.RandomProperty);

                this.ToTable("fooboo", "fooboodb");
                this.Property(t => t.Fooid).HasColumnName("Fooid"); 
                this.Property(t => t.Booid).HasColumnName("Booid");
                this.Property(t => t.RandomProperty).HasColumnName("randomproperty");

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must provide a lambda expression for the two `WithRequired` calls in order to specify the inverse navigation properties. Otherwise EF will assume that they belong to another additional relationship which is causing those foreign keys with underscores:

```
public class BooMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<Boo>
{
    public BooMapper()
    {
        //...

        this.HasMany(t => t.FooBoo)
            .WithRequired(fb => fb.Boo)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.Booid);
    }
}

public class FooMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public FooMapper()
    {
        //...

        this.HasMany(t => t.FooBoo)
            .WithRequired(fb => fb.Foo)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.Booid);
    }
}
```